# Data binding overwriting changes made to list in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have an application with a list of a complex type.

I can (seemingly) succesfully delete items from the list (the "laptop bag" has been deleted from the list) [Deleting "Laptop bag"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HMiK.png) -
[The collection after deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvphW.png)

[All seems well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcCnO.png)

However, the generated html has the [wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6tqK.png)
for some reason the description is different ONLY in the "hiddenfor" element.

What is really weird is that "Model.HardwareList[i].Description" is different when I print it normally compared to using the hiddenfor.

Whenever I do another post, my list is no longer correct.

If there's anything I can do to elaborate please say so.

It is not a mismatch of id when deleting, I have doublechecked to see if the id is correct and I also manually checked the collection after the deletion to see if it's correct.

## PageModel

```
public class HardwareModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Hardware> HardwareList { get; set; } = new List<Hardware>();

    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> HardwareNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    [BindProperty]
    public string ChosenNewHardware { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public int HardwareIdxToDelete { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    public void OnPostAddNew()
    {
        if (ChosenNewHardware != null && !HardwareList.Any(h => h.Description == ChosenNewHardware))
        {
            HardwareList.Add(new Hardware
            {
                Description = ChosenNewHardware,
                UnitPrice = 10
            });
        }
        GetData();
    }

    public void OnPostRemove()
    {
        var hw = HardwareList[HardwareIdxToDelete];
        HardwareList.Remove(hw);
        GetData();
    }


    public void GetData()
    {
        HardwareNames.Add("Dell P2419H");
        HardwareNames.Add("Laptop bag");
        HardwareNames.Add("Backpack");
        HardwareNames.Add("Mouse");
    }

}
```

## cshtml:

```html
@page
@model IctRequest.Pages.HardwareModel

@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/form.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}


<div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-holder" style="display:block; min-height:0px">
        <div class="form-content">
            <div class="form-items">
                @{
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.HardwareList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <br />
                        <div class="row rounded bg-secondary p-3 align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Remove">
                                    <div id="hiddenParams">
                                        @for (int h = 0; h < Model.HardwareList.Count; h++)
                                        {
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Description)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Quantity)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].UnitPrice)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Remarks)
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <input data-val="true" id="HardwareIdxToDelete" name="HardwareIdxToDelete" type="hidden" value="@i">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="OnPost" class="col-md-11 row">

                                <div class="col-md-3 m-auto"><h4 style="color:#fff">@Model.HardwareList[i].Description</h4>@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.HardwareList[i].Description)</div><div class="vr p-0"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 m-auto">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.HardwareList[i].Quantity,new { @class="form-control m-0 p-1" })</div><div class="vr p-0"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 m-auto">€@Model.HardwareList[i].UnitPrice @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.HardwareList[i].UnitPrice)</div><div class="vr p-0"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 m-auto">€0</div><div class="vr p-0"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 m-auto">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.HardwareList[i].Remarks, new { @class="form-control m-0" })</div>

                                <button type="submit" hidden>Save</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    }
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end pr-5">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="AddNew">
        @{
            var usedNames = new List<string>();
            for (int h = 0; h < Model.HardwareList.Count; h++)
            {
                usedNames.Add(Model.HardwareList[h].Description);
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Description)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Quantity)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].UnitPrice)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=> @Model.HardwareList[h].Remarks)
            }
            <select class="child_input" id="ChosenNewHardware" name="ChosenNewHardware">
                @for (int n = 0; n < Model.HardwareNames.Count; n++)
                {
                    if (!usedNames.Contains(Model.HardwareNames[n]))
                    {
                        <option>@Model.HardwareNames[n]</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option disabled>@Model.HardwareNames[n]</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
            //@Html.DropDownListFor(app => Model.ChosenNewHardware, new SelectList(Model.HardwareNames), new { @class = "child_input" })
        }

        <button type="submit">Add hardware</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

## Model:

```
public class Hardware
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TopdeskId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see some code to help you further

Comment: My bad, seems like I messed up the hyperlinks of the screenshots. I fixed them and added a code snippet

Comment: Can you share your `PageModel`? I can't reproduce your problem with just your cshtml code.

Comment: I added both pagemodel and the database model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just removed it from the `HardwareList`, but the value still exists in `ModelState`, so there will be a match error.

Please try to clear `ModelState`:

```
public void OnPostRemove()
{
    var hw = HardwareList[HardwareIdxToDelete];
    HardwareList.Remove(hw);
    ModelState.Clear();
    GetData();
}
```

Test Result:

[image]